# Assigning value to input field on nested:fieldAdded

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, firefox

I have an upload file field. On change of this field, I am triggering add nested field and on 'nested:fieldAdded' I am trying to assign the value to the input file field given in the new generated nested form by using the following jquery:

```js
$(document).off('change').on('change', '#add_gallery_image, #add_place_image',function () {
      if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var file = $(this)[0].files[0];

        file_selector_id = $(this)[0].id;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var association = ''

        if (file_selector_id.includes("add_gallery_image")) {
            association = 'tribute_galleries'
            limit_count = GALLERY_LIMIT_JS
        } else {
            association = 'tribute_places'
            limit_count = PLACES_LIMIT_JS
        }
        
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            file_src = e.target.result;            
            $(".add_nested_fields[data-association='" + association + "']").click();
        }
         reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
        // reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
    }
    })

$(document).on('nested:fieldAdded', function(event){
  if(file_selector_id!="") {
    var field = event.field;
    var dateField = field.find('.add_image');
    dateField[0].files = $('#' + file_selector_id)[0].files;
  }
})
```

```
<div class="upload-btn position-relative">
  <%= file_field_tag :image, :name => "tribute_gallery[image]", :class => "add_gallery_image image_uploader1", :id => "add_gallery_image","data-target": "#tribute_tribute_galleries_attributes_0_image-error", accept: 'image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg', "data-id": gallery_count.present? ? gallery_count + 1 : 1, disabled: gallery_count.present? && gallery_count >= GALLERY_LIMIT %>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="text-transform-none f-semi theme-btn w-100 text-center theme-large-btn">
    <span class="fa fa-upload mr-2 "></span> <%= I18n.t(:'tribute_setup.placeholders.upload_more') %>
  </a>
</div>


<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <div class="box-sec">
          <% positionCount = 0 %>
          <div class="row tribute_galleries_list" >
            <%= f.fields_for :tribute_galleries, wrapper: false, html: { autocomplete: "off"} do |gallery_form| %>
            <% if (gallery_form.present? && gallery_form.object.id.present? && gallery_form.object.image.present?) || (gallery_form.present? && !gallery_form.object.id.present? && !gallery_form.object.image.present?) %>
            <% positionCount = positionCount + 1 %>
              <%#= gallery_form.object.id.present? ? 'first_gallery_div' : '' %>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 fields first_gallery_div" data-count="<%= gallery_form.object.position.present?  ? gallery_form.object.position : (positionCount.present? ? positionCount : '') %>" data-id="<%= gallery_form.object.id.present? ? gallery_form.object.id : ''  %>" >
                <%= gallery_form.hidden_field :position, :value => gallery_form.object.position.present?  ? gallery_form.object.position : (positionCount.present? ? positionCount : ''), :class => 'gallery_position'  %>
                <div class="photo-img-sec position-relative ">
                  <div class="photo-img mb-2">
                    <%= gallery_form.file_field :image, :class => "add_image" ,:style=>"display:none" %>
                    <img src="<%= gallery_form.object.image.present? ? gallery_form.object.image : "/assets/gallery-dummy.png" %>" width="247" height="162" alt="personlized memorial page online" class="view_image_tag">
                    <% if gallery_form.object.user_id.present? && gallery_form.object.user_id != current_user.id  %>
                       <% if gallery_form.object.user.present? && gallery_form.object.user.user_detail.present? %>
                      <div class="photo-added">
                        <p class="small"><%= I18n.t(:'tribute_setup.placeholders.added_by') %>
                              <%= gallery_form.object.user.user_detail.first_name.present? ? gallery_form.object.user.user_detail.first_name : '' %> <%= gallery_form.object.user.user_detail.last_name.present? ? gallery_form.object.user.user_detail.last_name : '' %>
                        </p>
                      </div>
                      <% end %>
                    <% end %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <%= gallery_form.text_field :map_link, :placeholder =>  I18n.t(:'tribute_setup.placeholders.google_link'), :class => "theme-input form-control map_link_class" %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <%= gallery_form.text_field :title, :placeholder =>  I18n.t(:'tribute_setup.placeholders.title')+I18n.t(:'tribute_setup.placeholders.optional'), :class => "theme-input form-control name_class title_class" %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <%= gallery_form.text_field :description, :placeholder =>  I18n.t(:'tribute_setup.placeholders.description')+I18n.t(:'tribute_setup.placeholders.optional'), :class => "theme-input form-control description_class" %>
                  </div>
                  <%= gallery_form.link_to_remove "<i class='fa fa-times' aria-hidden='true'></i>".html_safe, class:"remove-btn remove_gallery_image" %>
                </div>
              </div>
              <%= gallery_form.hidden_field :user_id, :value =>  gallery_form.object.user_id.present? ? gallery_form.object.user_id : current_user.id %>
            <% end %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
          <p class='add_gallery_count' data-id="<%= gallery_count %>"><%= f.link_to_add "Add", :tribute_galleries, :data => {:target => ".tribute_galleries_list"}, :style => "display:none", :class=>"add_gallery_link" %></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Also, the above code is working fine for chrome but in firefox, it is assigning the last uploaded file value to all the newly generated nested forms along with the current generated nested form.

Comment: Hi Monika. nested_form gem is now 9 years old and has been archived. I recommend just not using it. Regarding your problem can you elaborate a bit maybe. By showing HTML for example. Because I first understood you wanted to generate a new field to an existing nested form. But after the code block, you say "the newly generated nested forms". Are you actually generating new nested forms?

Comment: Hi  @Maxence, thanks for replying. I have updated the query. Let me know if more information is required. I am grateful for your help, Thank you.

Comment: Your view is complex, written with an old ruby syntax, and a lot of logic through ternary operators. With a simple look at it, It is hard to tell what is breaking only in Firefox unfortunately...